# Convertir formato de fecha INT a un formato de fecha valido en PHP

Tags: php, date

Actualmente estoy haciendo una migración por cuestiones de seguridad, de un sistema de ya hace varios años hecho en **PHP 5.4** a **PHP 7.4.13** (y dentro de poco a la versión 8) con bases de datos en **mysql**, estoy deshaciéndome de las funciones obsoletas como **mysql_connec** y demás funciones por el estilo.

Un dato curioso que encontré es que cada que se guarda un registro, se guarda la fecha en que se creo, pero el campo es guardado en un campo de tipo **INT** según me comentan es por un estándar de fecha que se maneja en **Linux** o algo así, la verdad ya no tengo contacto con la persona que desarrollo el sistema, aparte que este sistema corre actualmente en un servidor con **Windows Server**, hasta aquí todo bien, pero al momento de consultar la información me regresa la fecha como un numero.
Por ejemplo **1629906405** ó **1615908244**, intente hacer la conversión utilizando la función [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) de PHP

```
$X=date('d-m-Y', $reg[fecha]);
echo $X;
```

y siempre me regresa **01-01-1970** sin importar cual sea el valor de la fecha

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: `echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", 1629906405);` devuelve `2021-08-25T15:46:45Z` no es un entero. Es un formato de fecha.

Comment: Debería funcionar con `date`. ¿Verificaste con el valor directamente `date('d-m-Y', 1629906405)`?.

Comment: Opino igual que @Sal debe de funcionar con date, no sé si tu código lo pegaste mal pero la palabra fecha que es la llave de tu arreglo asociativo, parece como si quisieras usar una constante, y se te olvidaron las comillas simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías probar

```
$X=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($reg[fecha]));
```

Saludos